# Change serverSorting programatically in kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo ui grid. In my page I two button that when user click button1, I want to disable paging and disable server sorting on grid and when user click button2, I want to enable paging and server sorting.

I disable paging by this code:

> $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.pageSize(0);

and enable paging by this code:

> $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.pageSize(10);

Also I want to disable server sorting by this code:

> $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.options.serverSorting = flase;

But it does not worked.
How to I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: I really don't understand the use-case for this. Neither of these "features" is natively supported by Kendo UI. Are you trying to prevent the query string parameters from being sent on the server request?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make it work is to initialize a new data source and assign it to the grid:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource( 
    $.extend(grid.dataSource.options, { serverSorting: false } ) 
);

grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The dataSource.serverSorting changes with this code.But sorting in grid not disable. Can you give me a sample in jsfiddle or same sites?